# Case Insensitive URLs with mod_rewrite

Tags: apache, url, mod-rewrite

I'd like for any url that doesn't hit an existing file, to do a lookup on the other possible cases and see if those files exist, and if so, 302 to them.

If that's not possible, then I'm ok with these compromises:

- Only check the lowercase version
- Only check the first path portion

For example http://example.com/CoOl/PaTH/CaMELcaSE should redirect to http://example.com/cool/path/camelCase (assuming the latter exists).

but of course a full solution is much more useful to me and others

Comment: I’d rather use a 301 than a 302.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

```
CheckSpelling on
```

Matches files and directories. See the [documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_speling.html) for details.

Comment: Is there an equivalent for the more recent versions?

Comment: Didn't seem that way; I have Ubuntu 12.04 LTS, Apache 2.2.22 and creating symbolic links to speling.load and speling.conf in `$APACHE/mods-enabled/` doesn't seem to allow folder names with the wrong case. (of course, speling.load and speling.conf are set up... maybe I should post another question.)

Comment: OK. It was me being silly with the symbolic links. Problem solved.

Answer (score 4):

I don't have Apache handy to test, but some combination of these rules should do what you want:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteMap lower int:tolower
RewriteCond ${lower:%{REQUEST_URI}} -U
RewriteRule [A-Z] ${lower:%{REQUEST_URI}} [R=302,L]
```

- A lowercase map to convert /SoMeThinG to /something
- A condition to see if the lowercase of the REQUEST_URI exists (-U is internal apache query)
- The rule to actually do the rewrite

I don't know if the RewriteMap can be applied in a condition, or if it only applies to a rule. These are based on [experts exchange accepted answer](http://www.experts-exchange.com/Software/Server_Software/Web_Servers/Apache/Q_24169533.html) and [a small orange forum discussion](http://forums.asmallorange.com/topic/9002-htaccess-mod-rewrite-and-file-exists/).

Your "ideal" solution is probably not possible unless you can enumerate every valid page on your site. If you only have a few valid pages, a combination of [RewriteMap](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.1/mod/mod_rewrite.html#RewriteMap) and a text map will do exactly what you need. If there are hundreds / thousands of pages you may need to write a script and use the `prg` directive.

If you can't identify every valid page, you would need to try every variant in case. Consider your URL as a binary string, with 0 for lowercase letter and 1 for uppercase. Just from your simple example you'd have to test 2^17 variations, 128k pages.

Comment: With `mod_rewrite` a malformed request like `/SoMeThinG.jpg` to a particular capitalization like `/SomeThing.jpg` ain't possible, right?

`mod_speling` would be perfect for my use case of serving mixed case media files case-insensitive.

The Shared Webhosting of my webhost uses Apache but `mod_speling` is off. Another webhost where I inquired for their Shared Webhosting uses Litespeed which has no `mod_speling` support at all.

Seems `mod_speling` is not common in Shared Webhosting.

Hence I look for an alternative way within `.htaccess` with other Apache modules.

Comment: As this is probably too much for a comment thread (that's 12y old) I asked this as a proper standalone question here: [Serve mixed case files case-insensitive on Linux Apache without mod_speling?](https://serverfault.com/questions/1123372/)

Answer (score 0):

Look up the Apache module mod_negotiation. It does exactly what you want:
http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_negotiation.html#multiviews

You can also pipe all requests to a single PHP file and let the PHP file do the checking for you.

Comment: That's close but seems mostly for adding extensions. Like a request for `foo` becomes `foo.xml` or `foo.html`. I'm trying to fix typos.