# RewriteRule from Main Page

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting, mediawiki

Please help with  setting/config of .htaccess file.

How to Rewriterule from address http://domain.com/main_page to http://domain.com ?

What i do or my .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine on
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
```

I tried `RewriteRule ^$ /Main_Page` but it doesnt work.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to prevent MediaWiki from redirecting the main domain to the "Main Page"?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26283433/how-to-prevent-mediawiki-from-redirecting-the-main-domain-to-the-main-page)

Comment: The solution nowadays is http://laxstrom.name/blag/2015/08/31/mediawiki-short-urls-with-nginx-and-main-page-without-redirect/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see three errors:

First: You try to redirect **back to front**.

```
RewriteRule ^$ /Main_Page
```

would redirect http://example.com/ to http://example.com/Main_Page.

Second: For your simple case the `RewriteCond` directives are **superfluous**. They check if the request file name does not exists as a file nor as directory. But you only want to redirect `/main_page` to `/`.

Third: **URLs are case sensitive**. On Windows web servers this does not matter. But your setup seems not to run on a Windows web server. If you really need case-insensitive redirecting, this is another question. See [Case Insensitive URLs with mod_rewrite](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1998156/220060).

Comment: Yeah i use Apache and i still tryin redirect from http://domain.com/Main_Page to http://domain.com and it doesnt work. do you can help with it ??? Probably some example or case as similar on that. with best regards

Comment: Try #9 with this code - RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}!redirecter 
RewriteRule (.*) [domain.com] [L]

Comment: This is a very basic question. StackOverflow is not the right place to get support for your problem. You need to learn the basics of URL Rewriting, then if you are stuck on a mildly hard problem, return here.

Comment: I kno dat StackOverflow is not place for support Mr. Nalply. i just think someone has a similar situation . Learning and learning , im dig on docs of Apache settings. Anyway thanks man.

Comment: Fourth, this will get you into a redirect loop as MediaWiki redirects from `/` to `/Main_Page`. When you don't have a clear understanding of how a system works, it is wiser to ask how you can achieve goal X, than to ask how you can do Y which you think is the way to achieve goal X - you are just not very good at turning goals into concrete steps at this point.