# How to prevent MediaWiki from redirecting the main domain to the "Main Page"?

Tags: mediawiki

I see a lot of questions about how to change the title of a MediaWiki Main Page or how to redirect it to another page, but I can't seem to find anything on how to 1) prevent MediaWiki from redirecting the main domain to the "Main Page", and 2) display a stand-alone page under the main domain.

In other words, how to do exactly what Wikipedia does when you go to [www.wikipedia.org](http://www.wikipedia.org)

Instead of redirecting you to "http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Main_Page", it displays a stand-alone custom page on the main domain (www.wikipedia.org).

How can I do that with MediaWiki?

Comment: See http://laxstrom.name/blag/2015/08/31/mediawiki-short-urls-with-nginx-and-main-page-without-redirect/ for a solution in MediaWiki 1.26. Also, this question was asked before on another SE site.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This isn't really a MediaWiki issue/function :) wikipedia.org is the top level domain with an own index page. en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ is the "real" article path (with /w/ as the ScriptPath). So you will be redirected to the Main page, if you open en.wikipedia.org/wiki :)

So, e.g., if your wiki installation is in domain.tld/wiki/ you just need to place your "own" webpage/opener into domain.tld/.

If a user opens domain.tld he will see your custom page, if he open domain.tld/wiki he will be redirected to domain.tld/wiki/Main_page.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Bummer, as I installed MediaWiki on the domain root and not in a sub-directory.  Is there any way to have MediaWiki display the "Main Page" under the main root **without** redirecting to "/wiki/Main_Page"?

Comment: If you have short urls enabled you should be able to add the DirectoryIndex to your .htaccess file to point to any other file then index.php and leave the rewrite rules to index.php.

Comment: I have no idea how to do that. :(  Should I create a new question about how to do that?  I'm not very familiar with customizing the .htaccess file.

Comment: Maybe a last hint: If you open your domain, you will be redirected to domain.tld/Main_page or domain.tld/index.php/Main_page? For the first case you will have some lines in your htaccess like RewriteCond and RewriteRule. Just add a new line "DirectoryIndex yourownindex.php" (where "yourownindex.php" is the site you want to show instead of Main_page). For the second case, it's better to open a new question i think.

Comment: That worked!  You have been incredibly helpful! Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Add in `.htaccess`

```
RewriteRule ^/*$ /index.php?title=Main_Page [L,QSA]
```