# How to call php api without .php extenstion in url

Tags: php, android, api

Hello when I call this api,

https://restapiaseem.000webhostapp.com/api/employees/get.php?id=10036

I receive below as response from my server,

```
{
"id": "10036",
"name": "Karun Nair",
"designation": "Marketing Head",
"mobile": "6988889799",
"email": "karunnair@gmail.com"
}
```

Is there any way to call this api look like this (removing the .php extension)
https://restapiaseem.000webhostapp.com/api/employees/get?id=10036

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to configure your web server(Apache Nginx, IIS) to Rewrite the URL or reroute them.

Comment: i am new to this can you explain please?

Comment: The solution is on the server part//configuration. Which server do you use ?

Comment: apache .htaccess 000webhost is my hosting

Comment: solved by writing these things on my .htaccess fileRewriteEngine on 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [NC,L]

Comment: You should take a look to the documentation of apache : https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/remapping.html or this interesting thread in SO https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43967770/mod-rewrite-handle-url-request-without-php-extension