# How do I make Linux server urls case insensitive?

Tags: php, linux

I am working a **website** which is deployed on a **linux server**. I have small changes to do on that. I have folder ***read***. The requirement is that if i enter the url  **localhost:80/tom/Read** or ..**/READ** or **/read** it need to navigate to **read.php** inside a read folder. I am struggling from 2 days. Please possible do the needful.

Thanks

Comment: Looks like you're looking for some URL rewriting technique. Apache does that quite well.

Comment: Hi Fabien... Can u describe it... I am new to linux servers.. How can i achieve Url Rewriting

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I make URLs case insensitive in Linux server](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14814419/608639), [Case Insensitive URLs with mod_rewrite](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1998156/608639), etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could point the Document Root at a path upon which you mount a case-insensitive filesystem (FAT32 for example), or use something along the lines of [mod_spelling](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_speling.html).

Comment: Another option is to use a RewriteMap rule, such as laid out at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2923658/convert-to-lowercase-in-a-mod-rewrite-rule1) SO question.

Answer (score 1):

You could write a htaccess to lowercase stuff

http://www.chrisabernethy.com/force-lower-case-urls-with-mod_rewrite/

Comment: Hi s.lenders   I created a file .htaccess under a root directory. Placed following code. mention below/

Comment: Add the htaccess in your question, can't in a comment

Comment: Lowercasing everything this way can have unintended consequences... like broken vendor code.