# problems with case sensitive when migrating php site from windows apache to linux apache

Tags: linux, apache, uppercase, lowercase, mod-speling

I have a problem that I have not been able to solve for several days.

I have a site developed in php with codeigniter framework running on a Windows XAMPP (apache) several years ago.

I have proposed to migrate the site to a linux cloud server (GCP), using docker images (apache, php, mariadb)

When migrating the site to the new server, it explodes everywhere because the code is referencing files that are in upper or lower case.

I have the mod_speling module enabled but the problem is not solved, surely I am doing something wrong! :(

I leave here the configuration of my **.htaccess:**

---

```
Options FollowSymLinks
   
<IfModule mod_speling.c>
 CheckCaseOnly on
 CheckSpelling on
</IfModule>
   
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
 RewriteEngine On
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
  
<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
 ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
</IfModule>**
```

---

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong???? please!!!!!

I tried disabling mod_speling and re-enabling it.

I tried Deleting my Rewrite rules, in case they conflict with the other module.

Comment: I'm having the same issue here, but trying to change case sensitive calls manually. Maybe someone has a better alternative.

Answer (score 0):

Seems that something like this was already answered in this question [Inconsistent case disaster php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26870299/migrating-a-legacy-php-project-from-windows-to-linux-inconsistent-case-disaster)