# URI is considered to be lowercased in htaccess. What might be wrong?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have been battling with this problem for a while. Suppose I go to `website.com/one/tWo`. In PHP `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` is `one/tWo`. I thought this had something to do with Apache URL rewriting so I checked `.htaccess` and removed everything and only left:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^one/two http://www.gosomewhereelse.com [R=301,L]
```

To my surprise, when trying 'one/tWo', Apache actually redirects me to www.gosomewhereelse.com.

Just to be clear, there is no redirection that happens from 'one/tWo' to 'one/two'. The URL doesn't change in the address bar and it still has the uppercase character but it's still matching with ^one/two

I tried everything I could think of and couldn't find a solution.

Comment: Since you are not using the `NC` flag, it should see the case. Think this is relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1998156/case-insensitive-urls-with-mod-rewrite

Comment: I'm not using the NC flag so it shouldn't match. As far as I know NC makes the regex case insensitive.

Comment: What OS are you using?

Comment: @JamieKitson Amazon Linux

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that it's not related to apache or PHP. The problem is from a third party software.

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/one/tWo$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.gosomewhereelse.com [R=301,L]
```

This also works:

```
RewriteRule ^one/t[W]o http://www.gosomewhereelse.com [R=301,L]
```